# How to group tableView data using sectionNameKeyPath (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've not been able to figure out how to do the following in Swift and looking for pointers.

I'm pulling string values from Core Data and displaying them in a UITableView...that's working and displaying all entries. I now want to 'group' these values by date created (also stored in Core Data) but am having a hard time implementing this group header...here's what I have:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    // Convert Date to String
    var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
    let dateTimePrefix: String = formatter.stringFromDate(sound.dateSaved)
    // Display the following in each rows
    cell.textLabel!.text = sound.name + " Saved: " + dateTimePrefix

    return cell
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to implement 'headers'? I already have the tableView in my Main.storyboard setup to 'Grouped' as a style.

--- Update

Thanks for the response below but, unfortunately, the examples are in Obj-C and I'm shooting for swift.

To expand, I have the following retrieving data from Core Data and displaying all in UITableView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Sound")
    self.sounds = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)! as [Sound]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.sounds.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")
    var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]

    // Convert Date to String
    var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd @ HH:mm:ss"
    let dateTimePrefix: String = formatter.stringFromDate(sound.dateSaved)
    // Display the following in each rows
    cell.textLabel!.text = sound.name // Sound Name
    // Display the following as each subtitles
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = dateTimePrefix // Sound Duration (Currently 'date')

    return cell
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how I go about 'grouping' each by month with a 'month' header using sectionNameKeyPath, I believe?  Specifically, which piece of code would need to be modified to break list into 'sections'.

Comment: Use NSFetchedResultsController to section the tableView, that is the preferred way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers:

1. You need to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` ("FRC") - check out the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html).  You will see that you specify the `sectionNameKeyPath` when initialising the FRC.
2. There is boilerplate code for updating a tableView using an FRC.  The easiest way to get this, and observe how the FRC works, is to create a project using Apple's Master/Detail application template, ensuring you select the "Use Core Data" option.  Play with it in that project to see how it works, and then cut/paste into your own project.
3. In your case, you want to the `month` (and presumably `year`?) as the section name.  There are a few ways to do that, but the easiest is to create a function (eg. `sectionIdentifier`) in your `Sound` class which returns a string with the section name, in the format you desire, derived from the `dateSaved`.  Then specify `sectionNameKeyPath:sectionIdentifier` when initialising the FRC.